# Sum values in column B for lines with matching column A values

Tags: python, csv

Extract from large csv looks like this:

```
Description,Foo,Excl,GST,Incl
A,foo,$154.52,$15.44,$169.96
A,foo,$45.44,$4.54,$49.98
A,foo,$45.44,$4.54,$49.98
A,foo,$154.52,$15.44,$169.96
A,foo,$0.00,$0.00,$0.00
A,foo,$50.16,$5.02,$55.18
B,foo,$175.33,$15.65,$190.98
C,foo,$204.52,$15.44,$219.96
D,foo,$154.52,$15.44,$169.96
D,foo,$154.52,$15.44,$169.96
D,foo,$45.44,$4.54,$49.98
D,foo,$154.52,$15.44,$169.96
D,foo,$145.44,$14.54,$159.98
```

I need to strip the dollar sign and for all lines containing matching `Description` values (`A` or `B` or whatever it may be), sum the `Excl` column values separately, the `GST` column values separately and `Incl` column values separately for that `Description` value.

End result should be a dictionary object containing the `Description` column as key and the sum totals of the `Excl`, `GST` and `Incl` columns matching the `Description`, example:

```
{
    "A": [450.08,44.98,495.06],
    "B": [175.33,15.65,190.98],
    "C": [204.52,15.44,219.96],
    "D": [654.44,65.40,719.84]
}
```

I'm completely stumped on how to perform the sum operation. My code only goes as far as opening the csv and reading in values on each line. Any enlightenment is appreciated.

```
import csv

def getField(rowdata, index):
    try:
        val = rowdata[index]
    except IndexError:
        val = '-1'
    return val

with open(csv, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    order_list = list(reader)

# Remove the header row in csv
order_list.pop(0)

for row in order_list:
    Desc = getField(row, 0)
    Excl = getField(row, 2)
    GST  = getField(row, 3)
    Incl = getField(row, 4)
```

Comment: Are the rows sorted by the first columns already?

Comment: You have to store the individual  sums in a dictionary with Desc as the key

Comment: @schwobaseggl - yes the data is already sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
import csv
import decimal

path = "Path to CSV_File.csv"

def removeSym(s):
    return float(s.replace("$", ""))

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    order_list = list(reader)

d = {}
for i in order_list[1:]:    #Skip reading the first line
    if i[0] not in d:
        d[i[0]] = map(removeSym, i[2:])   #Check if desc is a key the result dict. if not create 
    else:
        d[i[0]] = [float(round(sum(k),2)) for k in zip(d[i[0]], map(removeSym, i[2:]))]

print d
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': [450.08, 44.98, 495.06], 'C': [204.52, 15.44, 219.96], 'B': [175.33, 15.65, 190.98], 'D': [654.44, 65.4, 719.84]}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. You get the tick.